# KendoUI DataSource - OData querystring from filter attribute

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, odata

In a current project I would like to use the $http service of angular to make HTTP requests in my Kendo Data Sources, because I am using a response interceptor as described in this blog:

http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

I am using a KendoUI Grid in my application to display data, which I get in JSON format from the server. For some reason the odata query is cut off, if I specify a function in the "transport"-object and only the URL is sent to the server (example.com/odata/Foo), rather than the full query (example.com/odata/foo?$filter=barId lt 100).

I set up my Kendo DataSource like this:

```
$scope.foo = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        pageSize: 25,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                $http({
                    url: '/odata/foo',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: options.data
                })
                .success(function (result) {
                    options.success(result);
                });
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options, type);
            }
        }
```

HTTP requests using the $http service of angular work fine, I'm not having problems with that. The problem seems that I am unable to get the query part `(URL?$filter=[filter expression])` from the "filter" object in my kendo data source. I tried using the parameterMap option, but that did not give the desired results, either.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the $http service of angular to make HTTP requests? What have you tried so far?

Comment: HTTP requests using the $http service of angular work fine, I'm not having problems with that. The problem seems that I am unable to get the query part (URL?$filter=[filter expression]) from the "filter" object in my kendo data source. I tried using the parameterMap option, but that did not give the desired results, either.

Comment: Steffen, I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever find a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, I worked around the problem by using the error/success event handlers of the KendoDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this in the parameter map function:

```
kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options, type);
```

which doesn't seem to be called when the read property on the transport is mapped to a function. You can call this in the transport.read function:

```
transport: {
  read: function (options) {
      var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");
      $http({
        url: '/odata/foo',
        method: 'GET',
        params: odataParams
      })
      .success(function (result) {
        options.success(result);
      });
    }
  }
```